# IF ELSE Statement in SQL Server jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server job defined as follows but it shows error while executing. Please help sort out the problem

```
-- First clear out the destination table fast and easy without   
TRUNCATE TABLE [etimetracklite1].[dbo].[devicelogs];

-- Create table
DECLARE @tablename AS nvarchar(14);
DECLARE @yearnam AS nvarchar(4);
DECLARE @tabnam AS nvarchar(18);

IF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  1
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_1_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  2
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = '[devicelogs_2_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  3
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_3_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  4
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_4_]
END
ENDIIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  5
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_5_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  6
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_6_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  7
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_7_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  8
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_8_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  9
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_8_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  10
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_10_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  11
BEGIN
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_11_]
END
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  12
    SET @tablename = [devicelogs_12_]
END

SET @yearnam = YEAR(GETDATE());
SET @tabnam =  @tablename + @yearnam;

-- Execute a query
DECLARE @query_a AS nvarchar(500);

SET @query_a  = 'INSERT INTO etimetracklite1.dbo.devicelogs SELECT * 
FROM etimetracklite1.dbo.' +  [@tabnam];

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query_a;
```

The error I am getting is SQL error 102.

Comment: You must quote all SET @tablename = '[devicelogs_x_]'

Comment: ELSEIF doens't exist. use ELSE IF

Answer (score 1):

remove single quote from this condition

```
ELSEIF MONTH(GETDATE()) =  2
BEGIN
SET @tablename = '[devicelogs_2_]
END
```

and `ELSEIF`  should be `ELSE IF`

Answer (score 0):

This is a lousy data model.  You should be putting all the data into a single table.

If you printed out the SQL, you would probably spot the problem very easily.  (At least) one problem is the misconstructed square braces.  You have the year coming after them, for instance.

But, in any case, you can simplify your code:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [etimetracklite1].[dbo].[devicelogs];
--   Create table
DECLARE @tabnam AS nvarchar(18);

SET @tabname = 'devicelogs_11_[MM][YYYY]';

SET @tabname = REPLACE(REPLACE(@tabname, '[MM]', MONTH(GETDATE())
                              ), '[YYYY]', YEAR(GETDATE())
                      );

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO etimetracklite1.dbo.devicelogs SELECT * 
FROM etimetracklite1.dbo.' + @tabnam;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: The error  The replace function requires 3 argument(s). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 174) is displayed.

Comment: Dear Gordon Linoff

Comment: The replace function requires 3 argument(s). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 174).